# Were there farms in the early 19th century in England, which only focused on agriculture?

Tags: 19th-century, england, agriculture, great-britain, peasants

I think back in the day most farms consisted of both agriculture and livestock, but I think, there must have been exceptions.

I'm also especially interested in small-scale family-based farms.
The period of time I am most interested in, is the early 19th century (let's say from 1800-1820).

While I'm mostly focusing on England, situations in other locations will also be helpful.

Researching, I found that the prices for cereals went up quiet high around that time and it seems, that there was a lot of agriculture as I found that fallow land decreased a lot from the late 18th century on.

But all studies I found about farming, only focused on agriculture without paying attention to farm animals or did not go into detail about the types of farms at that time and delivered only a general overview.

Comment: Are you thinking of [market gardening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_garden) when you refer to "*agriculture*"? My understanding is that growing grain is relatively low margin and high-volume that is low intensity until harvest, while market gardening is low volume, high margin, and more steadily high intensity, farming.

Comment: Traditionally, I'd file 'animal husbandry' ("livestock") as part & parcel under 'agriculture'. Please define your terminology: you mean plant growing/centred agriculture? Please also cite your previous research ("found prices…", etc.)

Comment: Agriculture incudes raising both plants and animals.  Small family farms would almost certainly have chickens, ducks, or geese, and perhaps a dairy cow or goat.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for not defining "agriculture". You may have noticed that English is not my mother tongue. Anyways... by agriculture I ment only the raising of plants.

Comment: Would "farming" work for that?

Comment: "Farming" only means working on a field and growing plants in general, right?
If so, yes this would be the right word.

Comment: Farming includes both plants and animals: you can for instance be a dairy farmer (raising cows for milk). a hog (pigs) or poultry (chickens and other birds) farmer, and so on.  You might ask on the English Language & Usage site if there is a word that means just growing plants.  I can't think of one offhand, though curiously enough there's a common word - ranching - that means raising animals, usually cows, though other animals like deer or buffalo can be ranched.

Comment: @jamesqf - Well, being from where I'm from, I'm of course thinking of the song from Oklahoma, *The Farmer and the Cowman*, where the two are used consistently as opposites. That's what I get for getting my taxonomy from Rogers and Hammerstein.

Comment: Possibly the reason small-scale raising of animals is not mentioned is that both having a vegetable garden and raising animals (think chickens, rabbits, possibly a pig) even just for the own consumption was pretty much the norm. Not only for farmers but pretty normal for everyone who wasnt to poor or so rich that they'd afford buying all food. Not only in rural communites (Germany, maybe 70 years ago),  but even in town (earlier, but there were e.g. "downtown" chickens after WWII).

Comment: Well, thank you all very much and sorry for the confusion.